# Is the actual source code for GitHub on GitHub?

Tags: github

Is the code for the actual GitHub website/application hosted on GitHub?

Comment: GitHub isn't open source, but I expect they dogfood their service.

Comment: Perhaps in a private repo? Thanks for the edit btw.

Comment: Yes, I would expect so, but if what you're asking is where you can see it the answer is you'd need to get a job there!

Comment: Oh no. Was just curious :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, GitHub is developed on GitHub, using a variety of repositories.  Most of the code is private, but some tools are open source and in public repositories.  This is not in any way a secret, and multiple talks have been given about the way GitHub builds GitHub and the way the company uses it, which is relatively nontraditional.

This allows employees to test new features in their everyday work to make sure that they're functional and of excellent quality before release, and to think of new useful functionality to add.